# python dataframe modify column values on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

Have a python pandas dataframe with the following columns and rows

```
Server CPU Memory
10.0.0.1 2 4
10.0.0.2 4 8
server13 6 10
server12 2 8
10.0.0.3 2 4
```

I want to go back into the dataframe and do a dns lookup on the servers that have an IP. I have the details on how to do the DNS lookup with a condition and a function but I need help with knowing how to iterate through the dataframe to to modify the values in the first column.

Results should be

```
Server CPU Memory
server1 2 4
server2 4 8
server13 6 10
server12 2 8
server3 2 4
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # your data frame
df['Server']  # pick a column
# you can iterate over it or pick item by index
print(df['Server'][1])
for e in df['Server']:
    print(e)
# change some value
df['Server'][0] = 'server ip'
```

Comment: I recommend you elaborate on your answer.